# Block or swallow key stroke from reaching other threads

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I'm writing a system-tray application that listens to a usb-barcode scanner and launches an internet site once a matching barcode is read. (The barcode scanner gives a key sequence input like a keyboard).
Based on this article [Distinguishing Barcode Scanners from the Keyboard in WinForms](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/distinguishing-barcode-scanners-from-the-keyboard-in-winforms/).

I managed to write these features:

1. The program listens to all WM_IMPUT messages, and "catches" a scanned barcode even when it runs in the background and isn't in focus.
2. The program knows if it was a user typing the keyboard or the barcode-scanner scanning, and chooses only input from the scanner (yet the barcode is sent to the foreground window (that is in focus) as a regular key stoke sequence since the scanner acts like a keyboard).

The only thing I need to do is this:
3. If the input came from the barcode-scanner --> block it from being sent to any other application or thread. (Suppose you were writing an email, and then you scan - I don't want the barcode to be "typed" into your email).

Please help: Is it possible to block "key strokes" from all other threads? How to do it?

Thanks,
Hazar

Comment: This article explains how to do it and shows the problems involved. http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/distinguishing-barcode-scanners-from-the-keyboard-in-winforms/

Comment: That linked article goes about it all wrong.  Filtering keystrokes is much easier to do with a low-level keyboard hook, just return a non-zero value from the callback.  There is tons of C# code out there that implements a WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook.

Comment: @hanspassant, interesting. How do you know if the keystroke comes from the barcode scanner with a low level hook?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646290.aspx) link
This method should block all input(i hope your scanner will still come through though).