# How to read barcodes in background from barcode scanner

Tags: c#, usb, background-process, barcode, barcode-scanner

USB barcode scanner appears as keyboard in Windows desktop computer.
Browser application is used to continuosuly read barcodes from ID cards using

```
<form action="/authenticate" method="post">    
<input autofocus name="BarCode" type="text" value="">
<input type="submit" tabindex="-1">
</form>
```

Authenticate controller processes barcode and shows same page again on browser.

How to perform this process in background? If browser window in minimized and other application is in foreground, browser application does not remove barcodes anymore, they are sent to active windows application.

How to make it work in background? Application show receive keystrokes from specific usb port in background.
How to implement this ?  Can this done in javascript in browser or should some console application or service running in background created ?
Using Visual Studio with C# .NET 7 in Windows

I looked into RawInput API

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard#_Toc156395975

as described in answer

[Is it possible to scan barcodes into a process in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834915/is-it-possible-to-scan-barcodes-into-a-process-in-the-background?rq=2)

But this in C++. Where to find similar C# code?

Answer in

[Block or swallow key stroke from reaching other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023132/block-or-swallow-key-stroke-from-reaching-other-threads?rq=2)

Recommends to use WH_KEYBOARD_LL in system tray application but links in this question are dead.

https://github.com/stevemesser/rawinput  contains some sample code but does not have a way to run in background and stop scanned barcodes to reach to foreground application.

Comment: _USB barcode scanner appears as keyboard in Windows desktop computer...If browser window in minimized and other application is in foreground, browser application does not read barcodes anymore, they are sent to active windows application_: This is what one would expect from a _keyboard_ device. If I open _Notepad_ and start typing, should the keyboard input be sent to _MS Edge_? Of course not.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the manufacturer and model of the barcode scanner. One possibility, is to use the barcode scanner as a  _USB Serial_ (ie: [serial port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0))  device - refer to the documentation for your device for how to change the setting.

Comment: I dont know scanner model. It is widely used scanner, reads 1D barcode. Scanner is connected to USB port. If some specific model allows to solve the issue easily, I can change scanner to it. Then scanner should have API callable from browser from javascript or from desktop application. However this locks application to specific scanner. Maybe it is better to implement kayboard hook in windows so that keystrokes from scanner USB port are captured by background application. In this case any USB scanner can used.

Comment: Zebra Enterprise Browser has barcode API callable from javascript in browser: https://techdocs.zebra.com/enterprise-browser/latest/api/barcode/ How to run such browser in Windows computer with USB scanner? It looks like it runs only in Zebra mobile scanners.

Comment: Will Enterprise browser receive barcodes if running in background?

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid Scanner model is XB-7705H (China)